# Trying to detct a button press inside a fragment

Tags: android

I have created a fragment and want to detect when a button is press.  When I call  findViewById I get a error saying cannot resolve methed.

I'm assuming it is because this method does not exist in the fragment class.

How can I detect when a button inside a fragment is clicked.?

My test code:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Setup any handles to view objects here
    // EditText etFoo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etFoo);

    View mCall = findViewById(R.id.button);
    mCall.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {


}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.tedpo.testfragment.TestFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fooFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use:**

```
 View mCall = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

You have to `findViewById` of a `Button`in a current `View view` parameter in the Arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
Button button=view.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //DO SOMETHING! {RUN SOME FUNCTION ... DO CHECKS... ETC}
    } 
});
return view;
}
```

findViewById wont work because it does not know in which layout file item has to be searched.

Use `view.findViewById` instead of `findViewById` .`view.findViewById` will find item from `R.layout.fragment_test`